# How does the comments widget work in Dashing

Tags: comments, dashing

I recently started moving from DBA to SysAdmin, so I am very new to everything, please pardon if this is a stupid question.

I have figured most of the widgets out in Dashing, but I can not understand what what comments widget does, or how to feed data to it.

All the others are working properly and data being fed via bash and ruby.

If anyone can clarify what to send to it it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for twitter as it is stated in the widget: "Tweets tagged with #todayilearned"

```
# sampletv.erb
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
  <div data-id="twitter_mentions" data-view="Comments" style="background-color:#ff9618;" data-moreinfo="Tweets tagged with #todayilearned"></div>
  <i class="icon-twitter icon-background"></i>
</li>
```

Related job script is `jobs/twitter.rb` also you can check in github: https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/blob/master/templates/project/jobs/twitter.rb

`data-id` is `twitter_mentions`, it was matched, due to environment, I can't test it so far.